# I would rather you didn't / wouldn't

Tags: sentence-construction

If someone is going to do something very soon that I don't want to happen. For instance, someone is going to start playing on the computer. Which construction fits better or both are OK?

> Oh, you are going to play your game again now! I'd rather you didn't!
>
> Oh, you are going to play your game again now! I'd rather you
> wouldn't!

Answer (score 1):

The former.

The later is (although a very common mistake) entirely wrong.

Comment: I have some examples which are supposedly correct. Do you agree that they are correct? If you do, then what would you chalk their correctness to? ● I’d rather you would understand me better.  
● I would rather she would stop playing computer games.

Comment: The first is wrong. It should be *"I wish you **could** understand me better"*. In it's present form, apart for anything else, it makes it look as if 'you' are  deliberately misunderstanding. The second example does not work as it stands. However, "Given a choice, I would rather she stopped playing computer games" is correct.